# Inheritance chain with optional parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, optional-parameters

I wanted an inheritance chain to have an optional parameter. Most classes along the chain need to have the **parameter become a member sometimes**, but I also want to use the chain **other times without the parameter becoming a member**.

I thought of making the parameter optional a class and using import, but I want to avoid using class syntax for the member `optional`. And also because all classes along the chain are used in a dictionary as keys.

Alternatives to this? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a more Pythonic way?

```
class Top:

    def __init__(self, optional=None):

        if optional is not None:
            self.optional = optional
        return


class Middle(Top):

    def __init__(self, one, optional=None):

        if optional is not None:
            super().__init__(optional)

            self.one = one


class Bottom(Middle):

    def __init__(self, one, two, optional=None):

        if optional is not None:
            super().__init__(one, optional)
        else:
            super().__init__(one)

            self.two = two


a = Middle('one')
b = Middle('one', 'two')
c = Bottom('one', 'two')
d = Bottom('one', 'two', 'three')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1565175/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Top` already knows how to deal with `optional=None`; just pass the argument as-is. However, keep in mind that each class has to be prepared to receive and pass on unknown arguments, in case a class you didn't define inherits from any of these and adds its *own* arguments to `__init__`. (Consider a class `X` that inherits from both `Top` and some other class `Foo`, and `Foo` expects a keyword argument `bar`: `X(1, 2, 3, bar=5)` will eventually call `Top.__init__` without `bar` having been removed yet. Keyword arguments are a Very Good Idea when using `__init__` with `super`.)

```
class Top:

    def __init__(self, optional=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if optional is not None:
            self.optional = optional


class Middle(Top):

    def __init__(self, one, optional=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(optional, **kwargs)
        self.one = one


class Bottom(Middle):

    def __init__(self, one, two, optional=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(one, optional, **kwargs)    
        self.two = two
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to have the if statement in the `Top` (parent/base) class:

```
class Top:
    def __init__(self, optional=None):
        if optional is not None:
            self.optional = optional

# (you don’t need an explicit return in __init__)

class Middle(Top): 
    def __init__(self, one, optional=None):
        super().__init__(optional)
        self.one = one

# this applies to Bottom class as well
```

Now it doesn’t matter whether you provide this optional or not. Say you call `Middle` with no optional, the `one` attribute is set as expected and `Top.__init__` is called with `None` because the default parameter in `Middle` sets it to this if not provided. Since your parameter default is `None` in all classes, the presence (or lack of presence) of the optional is carried through, essentially.

Personally, I wouldn’t even include the if-statement. I would set the attribute as `None` so that later in your code if you try to access `obj.optional`, no `AttributeError` is raised. I believe one should keep attributes consistent through subclasses if they are inherited so that anyone trying to use  subclasses expect that all parameters used in `__init__` are used or set as attributes through the numerous `super()` calls up the inheritance chain and are not lost.